# Is it possible to include a footnote without symbol in KableExtra?

Tags: r, kableextra

When I use `add_footnote("Footnote 1")`, KableExtra always introduce a symbol in the footnote. But in many occasions, I would like to include a footnote without a symbol. For example, I would like to use `add_footnote("Source: Consumer Expenditure Survey")` to include information about the source of the data. But I do not want to have the symbol in front of "Source..." in my table. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can. :)

With current dev ver (should be on CRAN in a week or so), there is a new function called `footnote`. To get some non-labeled footnotes, just type

```
mtcars[1:5, 1:5]%>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T)%>%
  footnote(general = c("Note 1", "Note 2"), general_title = "")
```

Similar for html tables.

Comment: Thanks so much @Hao! The KableExtra package is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so if you want to use `kableExtra`.  If you're producing your document in LaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker for a way to do it in pure LaTeX.